# Ways to assign elements of two types to k labeled subsets.

Tags: combinatorics

A Stirling number of the second kind is the number of ways to partition $n$ elements into $k$ unlabeled subsets.

My first question: I want to know the number of ways to partition $n$ indistinguishable elements into $k$ labeled subsets.  Empty subsets are allowed.  (Feel free to point me to another question, or simply tell me the name of what I'm trying to compute.  I think it's probably been asked, but I have not yet found an answer to exactly this question.)

I have made attempts to work this out on my own, but I quickly get overwhelmed.

My second question (closely related): My elements are of two kinds, call them $A$ and $B$, with $n_A$ and $n_B$ of each, respectively, where $n=n_A+n_B$.  How many ways can elements of the two kinds be assigned to $k$ labeled subsets, again allowing empty subsets?  There is no distinction between $A$ elements, nor between $B$ elements.  I don't even know where to begin with this one.  Again, feel free to point me to another question.

I would be interested in knowing the answer of a more general version of the question, allowing $p$ different types instead of only 2, but my immediate need is only for the two-type result.

(These questions arise for me in developing a model in which I want to know the number of ways to sort $n$ organisms, each with trait $A$ or trait $B$ but not both, into $k$ environments.  Each such assignment defines what you might call an overall "meta-environment".  How many different meta-environments are there?)

Comment: Are the elements distinguishable? The number of ways of putting $n$ distinguishable elements into $k$ distinguishable boxes is $k^n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, they're not distinguishable, except for differing in being $A$ or $B$ in the second question.  I've edited to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, the solution is
$$f(n_A,k)f(n_B,k)$$
where $f(n,k)$ is the number of ways of putting $n$ identical balls
into $k$ boxes. Now $f(n,k)$ is the number of sequences $(c_1,\ldots,c_k)$
where $c_j$ are nonnegative integers with sum $n$. By the usual "stars-and-bars" argument,  $f(n,k)=\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, Lord Shark.   That makes sense, apart from the last step--still mysterious to me.  I understand combinations, but I'm not sure where the upper and lower sums come from.  I'll look up the stars and bars argument, though.  No need to reproduce it here.